# git hook script output is added with annoying "[K" postfix

Tags: git, hook

We have a git server that is using msysgit 1.7.11,

We have a setup where we added a post receive hook script,

This script is running a .sh script file that is calling to a .NET executable, so the output for 
this executable is going back to git and through our server back to the client with an annoying "[K" postfix (that is not shown in the console but it does in tools like "git gui"

Output:

```
...
remote: New deployment received.[K
remote: Updating branch 'master'.[K
...
```

Any way to fix this and remove the "[K" postfix?

Answer (score 2):

My psychic debugging skills indicate that this `[K` is probably part of a terminal escape sequence used for clearing to the end of the line (see http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm). It sounds like this is probably being generated by the .NET executable as it displays its status messages (which on a normal console, would overwrite one another instead of appearing on separate lines).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was some kind of escape sequence, the question is how do I avoid getting it?

Comment: I guess the first step is to figure out where it's coming from. What I would do is run your .NET executable, redirect its output to a file, and inspect that file in a text editor.